# Parsing data from a GET XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, python, rest, xmlhttprequest

This is hopefully a basic question, but I'm not able to find an answer in the million similar ones.

Let's say that I'm making a javascript GET request to my server with a variable being passed in the url, like so:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

How do I parse this in Python? With a post request, I'd just parse the data like so:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    fname = self.request.get('fname')
    lname = self.request.get('lname')
```

But I don't see how this would work if the data is passed through the url. Am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried rewriting your method as def get(self)?

Comment: I guess you're right-- I can just try it and see.